# What is the difference between a set-theoretic complete intersection, and a complete intersection.

Tags: graphing-functions

[image]
The [twisted cubic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twisted_cubic) (green) is a set-theoretic complete intersection, but not a complete intersection. What is the difference?

Comment: taken from: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commutative_ring

Comment: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/295601/set-theoretic-complete-intersections-in-toric-varieties